# iOS: Monotouch bindings for Appearance on Bar Style missing?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to convert this to Monotouch C#:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

But on the Appearance object there doesn't seem to be a Bar Style.

Is there a work around or alternative access point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This property is not decorated with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in the Objective-C header files. The initial MonoTouch Appearance work was based on that documentation (but we added more cases over time).

However the way Apple implement it's appearance support allows a lot of *undocumented* things will work (and hopefully continue to work if Apple change it's internal representation).

Anyway this means you can hack around this a bit, e.g. by doing something like:

```
IntPtr handle = UINavigationBar.Appearance.Handle;
var appearance = new UINavigationBar (handle);
appearance.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackOpaque;
```